# FFmpeg Capture remote screen

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying capture a remote screen via ffmpeg and x11grab, I run in my machine this command

`xpra start-desktop :20 --start-child=fluxbox`

this machine have the ip `192.168.1.15`

and in the remote capture I try run this

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f pulse -server 192.168.1.15 -i tarjeta01.monitor -f x11grab -framerate 25 -r 25 -i 192.168.1.15:20.0 -fflags nobuffer -f rtp -c:v h264_nvenc -preset llhp -profile:v baseline -level 4 -delay 0 -b:v 1500k -threads 4 -cbr 1 -r 25 -an udp://:5008 -f rtp -vn -c:a libopus -ar 48000 -ac 2 -ab 96k -application lowdelay -compression_level 0 -frame_duration 2.5 -cutoff 20000 -vbr constrained udp://localhost:5006
```

I make xhost + and xhost + 192.168.1.16 in the machine where run xpra but always receive this error

```
[x11grab @ 0x23e4ea0] Cannot open display 192.168.1.15:20, error 1.
192.168.1.15:20: Input/output error
```

I try xpra, Xephyr and xfvb but always get the same error

Thanks for all best regards

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The vfb started by xpra does not listen on TCP connections. Enabling TCP connections is not recommended either. To get decent performance, I would run ffmpeg on the same system where xpra is running.

Even if it was enabled, you would need to tell xpra to use sync-vfb, for details see [fix screen capture tools when used with xpra](https://xpra.org/trac/ticket/988)

Note: newer versions use a private pulseaudio instance, so ffmpeg won't be able to locate the pulseaudio server without some help: [Sound is leaking across multiple xpra sessions attached to different machines](https://xpra.org/trac/ticket/1266)